# Error: The getter 'textTheme' isn't defined for the class 'AppBarTheme'. - 'AppBarTheme' is from 'package:flutter/src/material/app_bar_theme.dart'

Tags: flutter

Launching lib/main.dart on sdk gphone64 x86 64 in debug mode...
Running Gradle task 'assembleDebug'...
../../.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dev/flutter_neumorphic-3.2.0/lib/src/widget/app_bar.dart:183:29: Error: The getter 'textTheme' isn't defined for the class 'AppBarTheme'.

- 'AppBarTheme' is from 'package:flutter/src/material/app_bar_theme.dart' ('../../Developer/flutter/packages/flutter/lib/src/material/app_bar_theme.dart').
  Try correcting the name to the name of an existing getter, or defining a getter or field named 'textTheme'.
  style: (appBarTheme.textTheme?.headline5 ??
  ^^^^^^^^^
  ../../.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dev/flutter_neumorphic-3.2.0/lib/src/widget/app.dart:89:7: Error: No named parameter with the name 'accentColor'.
  accentColor: theme.variantColor,
  ^^^^^^^^^^^
  ../../Developer/flutter/packages/flutter/lib/src/material/theme_data.dart:290:11: Context: Found this candidate, but the arguments don't match.
  factory ThemeData({
  ^
  Target kernel_snapshot failed: Exception

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

- Where:
  Script '/Users/mac/Developer/flutter/packages/flutter_tools/gradle/flutter.gradle' line: 1201
- What went wrong:
  Execution failed for task ':app:compileFlutterBuildDebug'.

> Process 'command '/Users/mac/Developer/flutter/bin/flutter'' finished with non-zero exit value 1

- Try:

> Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace.
> Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
> Run with --scan to get full insights.

- Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 10s
Exception: Gradle task assembleDebug failed with exit code 1

I tried to update all packages in pubspec.yaml. there is no Code error as per Android Studio.

Comment: can you share your flutter version and the code where you are using `'textTheme`

Comment: version: 1.0.0+1

environment:
  sdk: ">=2.16.1 <3.0.0"